# Debugging an Ajax call from DataTables in ASP.NET / Razor and C#

Tags: c#, ajax, razor, datatables

I have used DataTables in the past with MVP pages but am working with Razor and C# this time. I have setup my DataTable on the page `RTSkills.cshtml` and configured the Ajax call as shown here:

[DataTables Ajax code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEcrr.png)

In the `RTSkills.cshtml.cs` code behind file, I have my function `OnGetLoadDataSkillsetAsync()`:

[C# code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmEgQ.png)

Which I have tested and is returning JSON correctly when tested as a standalone function.

The problem is it doesn't seem to be returning it when 'requested' by DataTables. I don't think the function is actually being called as I have a breakpoint set on entry which is not 'triggered'. However I am getting an error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

when I look in the console window of the browser (FireFox):

[Firefox console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZSNu.png)

After some help from the DataTables community  I can see that the `OnGet()` call is being accessed from the `RTSkills` page, but it is not calling the `OnGetLoadDataSkillsetAsync()`:

[OnGet()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGMhz.png)

So it seems I am returning the view/page itself:

[Firefox Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma1Hk.png)

I did have the default `OnGet()` commented out and there was no difference. I think my problem is that I'm not calling the `OnGetLoadDataSkillsetAsync()` but I can't see what I'm doing wrong in the code below - any ideas anyone?

[Full Ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnKCr.png)

Cheers,

David

Comment: I have resolved this issue by changing the OnGetLoadDataSkillsetAsync() function from an Async Task to a 'normal' function, removed the 'await's and renamed to OnGetLoadDataSkillset(). This now is now called correctly.